# redirecting screen output from python logging to a file

Tags: python, bash, redirect

How can I redirect the output of python logging statements to a file at run time using redirection?

I am using python 3.7 in Debian. When I redirect the output from a python script containing a print statement to a file, I get the expected result - a file containing the output.

If I use logging.debug to create the screen output and redirect this to a file, I get the output displayed on the screen and a zero size file.

**python_test.py**

```
print('hello')
```

```
python python_test.py > test.txt
more test.txt
hello
```

**python_logging_test.py**

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')

logging.debug('from logger')
```

```
python python_logging_test.py > test2.txt
from logger
ls -al test2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bart bart 0 Mar 31 20:00 test2.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

logging does not use the stdout stream, it uses the stderr output stream.

Redirect the stderr stream:

**method 1**

```
python python_logging_test.py 2> test2.txt
```

```
more test2.txt
from logging
```

**method 2**

Use stdbuf:

```
stdbuf -e L python python_logging_test.py > test2.txt
```

```
more test2.txt
from logger
```

from stdbuf --help
-e, --error=MODE   adjust standard error stream buffering
If MODE is 'L' the corresponding stream will be line buffered.

Comment: is this "python python_logging_test.py 2> test2.txt" in crontab?

Comment: I run these commands from the command line, not using crontab.